# REST-ASSURED posting empty request body for generated object

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm using rest assured to send a post with a generated body from a model class. The model class uses the builder pattern and I confirmed that it is getting built correctly:

```
Request body:
McpSalesInvoicesPost(invoices=[McpSalesInvoices(type=PRE_ORDER, amount=212.0, currencyCode=INR, transactionDate=2020-10-24T22:43:24, payments=[McpSalesPayments(type=CASH, amount=212.0, currencyCode=INR, reference=reference text sample 376, transactionDate=2014-08-20T19:23:51)])])
```

When I use that object in the rest assured post call I get an empty body in the request. Here is the rest assured code:

```
           response = SerenityRest
                .given()
                .filters(Arrays.asList(new RequestLoggingFilter(), new ResponseLoggingFilter()))
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .header(new Header("x-openapi-clientid", "client-id-1"))
                .body(requestBody)
                .when()
                .request(verb, SALES_BASE_URL + endpoint);
```

where request body is the built object mentioned above and this gives:

```
Body:
{
    
}
```

for the request. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

A

Comment: Not a clue, can you double check `requestBody` by printing it right before calling API?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try .with().body(object).

```
response = SerenityRest
                .given()
                .filters(Arrays.asList(new RequestLoggingFilter(), new ResponseLoggingFilter()))
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .header(new Header("x-openapi-clientid", "client-id-1")).with().
                .body(requestBody)
                .when()
                .request(verb, SALES_BASE_URL + endpoint);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).